# Click on Cancel Button in Print Document Message

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on the cancel button which is in the print document in chrome. So here is the HTML

```
<cr-button class="cancel-button" aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0">

    Cancel

  </cr-button>
```

I have tried the following but did not work

```
        driver.get(resume_url)
        driver.maximize_window()
# Trial
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('cancel-button').click()
# Trial
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Cancel').click()
```

Nothing of these were successful and it returned the following error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Cancel"}

  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
```

Comment: Have you tried `find_element_by_class_name`? Or by xpath?

Comment: @Armadillan yes the same error occured

Comment: Then I need more information about the HTML. Could the button be in a different iframe? What webpage are you accessing?

Answer (score 0):

Locating elements by link text only works for anchor elements.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text

To use the class name as a selector, you just append a period to the beginning. Does this work?

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.cancel-button').click()
```